# Sum column values of a table based on a value of another column

Tags: excel

Say that we have a table with 2 columns (Places, Sales), in column "Places" we have the values Home, Work, Other, and in column "Sales" we have the sales values. I want to sum the values in column "Sales" but only the ones that match a given "Home" place. Can I do that without using vba?

Comment: Yes you can. Please show and example of your data, desired outcome, and what you have tried. You can read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS()` function like-

```
=SUMIFS(Table1[Sales],Table1[Place],"Home")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using sumif function.
Sumif('select the range of category i.e. Places','select the category i.e. Home','range which needs to be summed i.e. sales')

Column A |Column B |Column C |Column D
1 Places   |  Sales  |         | Home
2 Home     |   10    |         |
3 Work     |    8    |         |
4 Other    |    9    |         |
5 Cafe     |   12    |         |
6 Home     |    6    |         |
7 work     |    3    |         |

for the above table if you use the =SUMIF(A1:A7,$D$2,B1:B7) or =SUMIF(A:A,"Home",B:B)
you will get your answer as 16.

[Snip of table and formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdCN1.png)
[with formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4tuO.png)

Comment: But I need to use table elements reference instead of cell name reference. Because is a dinamic table gets bigger when you add data.